# Registering SQL Spatial View in ArcSDE and updating Row_ID?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, sql-server

I am having issues registering an inner join SQL view with a spatial column in ArcSDE. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the background info:

ArcSDE 10, SQL Server Enterprise 2008 R2, SQL 'Geometry' Spatial Type, Non-Versioned database, DBO schema, My Windows login is a sysadmin user

Here is the goal:

The view I am trying to register is an inner join of a polygon feature class to a table. The left of the join is the table, which in the database has a ONE_TO_MANY relationship with the feature class, where the feature class is the primary key as ONE and the table is the foreign key as MANY. I need to display in ArcMap the polygon geometries of all the feature class records as joined to the table. Since this is a ONE_TO_MANY relationship, it will result in coincident/duplicate polygon geometries, but that's OK.

Initially I am adding the view to SDE using sdetable -o create_view:

```
sdetable -o create_view -T Int_Veg_TEST -t "Interaction,Vegetation" -c
"Interaction.ObjectID AS INT_OID, Interaction.INT_UUID, Interaction.EVENT_UUID,
Vegetation.ObjectID AS VEG_OID, Vegetation.VEG_UUID, Vegetation.Shape" -w
"Interaction.EVENT_UUID = Vegetation.VEG_UUID" -i -D
```

This finishes OK, but the resulting view only displays the count and geometries from the right of the join (feature class) and I need it to display the feature class geometry and count as joined to the left (table). I would love to set the Row_ID when creating the view but that option is not available in -o create_view. When using the sdetable -o describe option, it shows that ArcSDE has pulled the feature class ObjectID field as the Row_ID:

```
Table Int_Veg_TEST:
Column name    Attribute    type    Null?  Length,DPs   RowID Column?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT_OID                  SE_INT32  NOT NULL   10
INT_UUID                 SE_UUID   NULL       38
EVENT_UUID               SE_UUID   NULL       38
VEG_OID                  SE_INT32  NOT NULL   10
VEG_UUID                 SE_UUID   NULL       38
SHAPE                    SE_SHAPE  NULL        0
OBJECTID                 SE_INT32  NOT NULL   10          SDE Set
```

From here I am having trouble using command line sdetable or sdelayer to update the Row_ID of an existing spatial view. Anyone know if this is possible using command line?

I can update the Row_ID manually in the sde_table_registry rowid_column, and it works. All polygon geometries for the join are displaying in ArcMap.

2 problems here though:

A: SDE still thinks it is maintaining the Row_ID. And I can't find where in the sde registry to manually update this to USER.

```
Table Int_Veg_TEST:
Column name   Attribute   type Null?   Length,DPs   RowID Column?

INT_OID       SE_INT32     NOT NULL        10          SDE Set
INT_UUID      SE_UUID      NULL            38
EVENT_UUID    SE_UUID      NULL            38
VEG_UUID      SE_UUID      NULL            38
VEG_OID       SE_INT32     NOT NULL        10
SHAPE         SE_SHAPE     NULL            0
```

B. I'd rather not update the SQL tables directly.

I've also tried creating a new view using SQL Server Management Studio and registering it in SDE using sdelayer -o register, but this also does not work:

SQL:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO 

CREATE VIEW [Int_Veg_TEST]

WITH SCHEMABINDING

AS 

SELECT dbo.INTERACTION.OBJECTID AS INT_OID, dbo.INTERACTION.INT_UUID,     
dbo.INTERACTION.EVENT_UUID, dbo.VEGETATION.OBJECTID AS VEG_OID, 
dbo.VEGETATION.VEG_UUID, dbo.VEGETATION.SHAPE

FROM dbo.INTERACTION
INNER JOIN dbo.VEGETATION ON dbo.INTERACTION.EVENT_UUID = dbo.VEGETATION.VEG_UUID

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Ix_INT_OID_UNIQ_CLUSTERED
ON Int_Veg_TEST (INT_OID)

GO
```

command line:

```
sdelayer -o register -l Int_Veg_TEST,Shape -e a -t Geometry -C INT_OID,USER -i -D 

Error: Underlying DBMS error (-51).
Error: Cannot Create Layer.
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0: Cannot alter 'INT_VEG_TEST' because it is not   
a table.
```

More information is available.

Answer (score 4):

This has been resolved.

sde_layer error is a bug in ArcSDE 10.0 service packs 1 & 3.  Service pack 2 works fine and ESRI tech support claims 10.1 will work fine too.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.  Please go ahead and mark it as answered.